# The curious case of "These following + a plural" vs "The following + a plural"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

From my understanding, **the following + a plural** generally serves as an introduction, letting the reader know that they're about to be presented with a list of some sort.

Example:

> *The following questions are exceedingly difficult.*

This phrase is often seen in exams or when a set of data needs to be presented in a scientific paper, among other uses.

However, if I change up the example by just a little bit:

> ***These** following questions are exceedingly difficult.*

Now the sentence becomes strange, and seemingly ungrammatical.

Native speakers tend to lean more towards the first example rather than the latter. This is further supported by Google Ngram, where [the number of usages for **the following** surpasses that of **these following** by quite a margin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these%20following%2Cthe%20following&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20following%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20following%3B%2Cc0).

One might think that this is an opinion shared by most native speakers, and that **these following + a plural** is only used by those unfamiliar with the language. However, the phrase does appear in several publications throughout different periods, many of which seem to have been written by people with extensive - or at least some - experience in writing. Here are a few examples:

**[Chemistry: A World of Choices](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qr9QAAAAYAAJ&q=%22these%20following%22&dq=%22these%20following%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2scnAtdvcAhVZVH0KHQaxDhc4ChDoAQgsMAI)**, by *Paul B. Kelter, James D. Carr, Andrew Scott*, published by McGraw-Hill in 2003.

> Which of these following compounds are covalently bonded? Which have ionic bonds? HCI, NaCl, CCI<sub>4</sub>

[**The History of the Twelve Great Livery Companies of London**](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Qe9NAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA485&dq=%22these%20following%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwm7_0ttvcAhVIXisKHTU1DCoQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22these%20following%22&f=false), by *William Herbert*, published in 1836.

> These following gave lesser
> Sums.
> Sir William Craven
> [...]

**[Eighty Years Progress of the United States](https://books.google.com/books?id=OiEaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA178&dq=%22these%20following%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUwbveutvcAhXDfysKHZJiA7Q4ChDoAQg6MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22these%20following%22&f=false)**, by multiple authors, published in 1861.

> The totals were composed of these following grains

**[Following Searle on Twitter: How Words Create Digital Institutions](https://books.google.com/books?id=FtcZDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22these%20following%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu8Pywzd3cAhUFfH0KHXSCBHkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22these%20following%22&f=false)**, by Adam Hodgkin, published by University of Chicago Press on Feb 21, 2017.

> The reason for this is that the deontic effects of **these following** (blocking, etc.) decisions are produced by the ways in which messages are syndicated or circulated within Twitter. All **these following** decisions result in what Searle elsewhere calls "standing Status Function Declarations."

Due to the significant number of usages present in books throughout different periods, I do believe that **these following** is entirely appropriate and grammatical. Judging by how they're used, I'd say it's also identical to **the following** when it comes to meaning, too. For some strange reason, however, **these following** seems to have fallen out of favor, as seen in Google Ngram:

[image: "these following" showing what looks like exponential decay from 1820 to 2000]

Here are my questions:

- Are there any differences between the two that I might not have noticed which could affect how they are used?
- **If so**, then what exactly are those differences?
- **If not**, then why is **these following** not as widely used as **the following** despite being so close in meaning to each other?

Comment: You can say "the following questions", or "these questions" but not a hybrid of both, although some obviously do.

Comment: Seems to me that _following_ in _these **following** items_ is rather redundant.  These points to something specific.  Consider this:  "Pick up _the_ items."  "Which items?"  "_These_ items."  In the first sentence, _the items_ is unclear as to which items are meant.  In the last sentence, _these_ is used to indicate a specific set of items, rendering _following_ unnecessary.  It is used with _the following items_ to avoid that ambiguity from the start.

Comment: Google Books shows a few examples of *these following questions* along with plenty of results for *these remaining questions* and some of *these perplexing questions* so I don't see evidence of a general rule for these+-ing+questions. I agree it might be a bit unnecessary at times, though, and less familiar.